# How to get a balanced score between three numbers of differing sizes?

Tags: statistics

I have four items, each scored in three different categories. I would like to end up with one "final" score, which is a balance between the three scores.

```
----------------------------------------------
ID | Score 1 | Score 2 | Score 3 | Final Score
1  | 0.3     | 12      | 70      |
2  | 0.7     | 19      | 95      |
3  | 0.6     | 22      | 61      |
4  | 0.2     | 9       | 29      |
----------------------------------------------
```

Because each of the three metrics is equally important, I would like each one to have the same weight. However, simply adding them won't suffice, since one score is much bigger than the other (so in the example above, Score 3 would be likely to autonomously determine the final score). How could I compute a final score in which each of the three scores has the exact same 'influence'?

Comment: There are three obvious ways. (1) use the max and min possible marks for each score, So if score 1 had a possible range of 0-1, score 2 of 0-25, and score 3 of 0-100, you could take 100 times score 1 + 4 times score 2 + score 3. (2) rank and add the ranks, so for score 1 you would rank them as 2,4,3,1, for score 2 as 3,2,1,4 and for score 3 as 3,4,2,1. Add to give 8,10,6,6. (3) use the range of marks, so score 1 has range of 0.2 to 0.7, normalise that on 0.10, so 0.2 goes to 0, 0.3 goes to 2, 0.6 to 8, 0.7 to 10 etc.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with the final score. My first suggestion is to reduce them all to percentages or fractions of full scale, so if Score1 is in range 0-1 and Score2 in the range 0-25 and Score3 in the range 0-100 I might set the final score to be $(S1+S2/25+S3/100)/3$, but under different conditions I might prefer something else.